# C# GroupByMany to List-of-Lists

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to separate out a list of a class by multiple values. This is a simplification of what I'm working with, using cars, years and colors for readability.

```
class car
{
    public string color;
    public int year;
    public int index;
}
```

Lots of classes are generated and added to a list.

```
List<car> carList = new List<car>();
```

I then need to separated out the list by multiple values (color and year), to get an input like this.

```
Yellow, 2008 //List.Count = 2
    Car 1
    Car 2
Yellow, 2009 //List.Count = 2
    Car 3
Red, 2012 //List.Count = 2
    Car 4
    Car 5
// queryItemsByColorYear.Count = 4
```

I've attempted to do something like this but it's not giving the desired output.

```
var queryItemsByColorYear = carList.GroupBy(cars => new {cars.color, cars.year})
                            .Select(group => group.ToList())
                            .ToList();
```

Alternatively, I thought that the below would output a list of lists to iterate through like so

```
Yellow //List.Count = 2
    2008     //List.Count = 2
        Car 1
        Car 2
    2009 //List.Count = 1
        Car 3
Red //List.Count = 1
    2012 //List.Count = 2
        Car 4
        Car 5
// queryItemsByColorAndYear.Count = 2
```

Here is what I tried to use...

```
var queryItemsByColorAndYear = from cars in carList
                                        group car by new {color = car.color, year = car.year} into colorGroup
                                        select colorGroup;
```

Thanks

Comment: Your approach seems good for me.

Comment: Great question you made.

Comment: kindly little detail me Car 1 Car 2 Car 3 .. Numeric values represent to index of car w.r.t color and year.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/COAUj4) for you.  Here is my code to fit the formatting and attributes that you want:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var carOne = new Car()
        {color = "Yellow", year = 2008, index = 1, name = "Car One"};
        var carTwo = new Car()
        {color = "Yellow", year = 2008, index = 2, name = "Car Two"};
        var carThree = new Car()
        {color = "Yellow", year = 2009, index = 3, name = "Car Three"};
        var carFour = new Car()
        {color = "Red", year = 2012, index = 4, name = "Car Four"};
        var carFive = new Car()
        {color = "Red", year = 2012, index = 5, name = "Car Five"};

        var lstCars = new List<Car>() {carOne, carTwo, carThree, carFour, carFive};


        var groupCars = lstCars.GroupBy(x => new {x.color, x.year}).Select(t => new{Color = t.Key.color, Year = t.Key.year, ListCount = t.Count(), Names = t.Select(z => z.name).ToList()}).ToList();


        foreach (var item in groupCars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} \t List Count - {1}", item.Color, item.ListCount);
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", item.Year);
            foreach (var name in item.Names)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public string color;
    public int year;
    public int index;
    public string name;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Linqpad.

```
 void Main()
    {
        var car1 = new car() { color = "Yellow", year = 2011, index =1 };
        var car2 = new car() { color = "Green", year = 2018, index =2  };
        var car3 = new car() { color = "Green", year = 2018, index =3  };
        var car4 = new car() { color = "Red", year = 2014, index =4  };
        var car5 = new car() { color = "Yellow", year = 2014, index =5  };

        List<car> carList = new List<car> {car1, car2, car3, car4, car5};

        carList.GroupBy(entry => new { entry.color, entry.year }, entry => entry.index, (a, b) => new { Key = a, Value = b }).Dump();
    }

    // Define other methods and classes here
    class car
    {
        public string color;
        public int year;
        public int index;
    }
```